# Can't serve "hidden" wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm switching a Wordpress site from Apache to Nginx.

We're trying to obfuscate the fact that it's a Wordpress site (I don't know why, but those are the requirements).

There are a few calls to static assets within the wordpress directory, so it's not perfect.

For the most part, it's working (www.example.com and other pages within show up properly), but I can't get the Admin page to work.

When you go to example.com/wp-admin, the server should load /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php, but I keep getting a 404.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. This is my server conf:

```
server {
    server_name *.example.com;
    root /var/example.com/docroot;

    access_log  logs/access.log;
    error_log   logs/error.log debug ;

    gzip off;

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
   rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

   # Rewrite wp-content to pretend we don't use Wordpress
   location ~ ^/content/(.*)$ {
       alias /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-content/$1;
   }

   location ~ ^/wp-content/(.*)$ {
       alias /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-content/$1;
   }

   location ~ ^/includes/(.*)$ {
       alias /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-includes/$1;
   }

   location ~ ^/wp-includes/(.*)$ {
       alias /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-includes/$1;
   }

   location /wp-admin {
       alias /var/example.com/docroot/wordpress/wp-admin;
   }

    # Basic php configuration
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

# static assets and blocking specific access
    include sites-enabled/common.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things I did to get this to work:

Proxy_pass instead of alias

```
location /wp-admin {
    proxy_pass $scheme://www.dev4.railrode.net/wordpress/wp-admin/;
}
```

And for the try_files directives, added a wordpress$uri option:

```
try_files $uri /wordpress$uri =404
```